# How to route all traffic through another server at the same subnet?

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn, route, openwrt

I want to forward all traffic that comes from clients `(192.168.1.0/24)` out of openwrt gateway `(0.0.0.0/0)` to the Server openvpn tunnel.

Server has an openvpn tunnel. It has also set options:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
tun0 is the default gateway
```

Openwrt is a default gateway to the Internet. 
So if I manually change default gateway on client side to server ip `192.168.1.2` - it works.

```
                            +------------+                                       
                            |  INTERNET  |                                       
                            +------|-----+                                       
                                   |                                             
                                   |                                             
                                   |                                             
                          +--------|-------+                                     
                          |    OpenWRT     |                                     
                          |                |                                     
                          | 192.168.1.1/24 |                                     
                          +---|----|-------+                                     
                              |    |                                             
                              |    |       +-------------+                       
                              |    |       |    Server   |                       
                              |    |       |             |                       
          +---------------+   |    |--------192.168.1.2  |                       
          |    Client     |   |    |       |             |                       
          |               ----+    +-------|tun0         |                       
          | 192.168.1.101 |                |             |                       
          +---------------+                +-------------+
```

#### What I tried?

Marked all packets except one from server:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i br-lan '!' -s 192.168.1.2 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Then route them via new route table which has default route through `192.168.1.2` but have no luck with it. The traffic stucks in router.

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.2 table vpn
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup vpn
```

#### My Sollution

Actually, while I writing this I recognized that I can use dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.2 on dnsmasq router to send all clients preferred gateway. And it works :) Probably this is best sollution. But, is it possible to route all traffic  with iptables and routes on openwrt side?

Comment: Regarding your solution.  That's probably the way I'd do it.   If you add some routes to OpenWRT and get it to forward, it's extra hops for no benefit and unnecessary extra work/load for the router.